Type for Java function that takes a class as argument and returns an instance of the class
I know I can have a function that takes a Class and returns an instance parametrized with that class like so
public <T> Broker<T> apply(Class<T> clazz){
   //code
}

My question is how can my class implement the Function<T,R>?
Following does not work:
class MyClass implements Function<Class<?>, Broker<?>>

Neither does this, since my class cannot be parametrized to one type, and a single instance will serve different classes
class MyClass<T> implements Function<Class<T>, Broker<T>>


Show some typical intended usages of your MyClass.

define 'does not work' in this example. Are you getting a compiler error on the line you pasted in your example question here? Then paste that error in. Are you using that class a certain way and that causes an error? Paste the usage and the error. All compiles well but you get runtime errors? Paste the stack trace, ensuring the line numbers in the trace line up, or alternatively clarify which line is pointing at what. I'm pretty sure it's the middle (you are 'using' it and this is causing compiler errors), but, help us help you and all that.

As a separate issue, this sounds like a code smell. Generally trying to translate an instance of java.lang.Class to produce an instance of the class it represents, is no good. Constructors don't do type safety. This is what factories are for.

@k314159 Ok: this.aBroker = this.myClass.apply(AClass.class);

You cannot implement Function<T,R>. How about writing your own functional interface?

@rzwitserloot first of all, I am depending on an external library that takes a class and returns an object that is parametrized for that class for ORM. Second, by "do not work", I mean I get a compiler error where the method that I posted first is not recognized as  implementation of Function.apply, so it both required me to write a Function.apply in my class, as well as complains about the @Overwrite annotation

@Sweeper what do you mean "you cannot implement Function<T,R>"?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

A single instance will serve different classes… and will produce the same type of Broker for all of those classes?

if you remove the type declaration from the method (1st snippet), the last snippet will compile with it: class MyClass<T> implements Function<Class<T>, Broker<T>> { @Override public Broker<T> apply(Class<T> clazz){    //code } }  (but not sure if that is useable, I didn't understand the reason for that)

@k314159 I mean the apply method shown in the question has one type parameter, but Function requires apply to have no type parameters, so this class cannot implement Function. Did I misunderstand the question?

@Sweeper the apply function itself doesn't have to be parameterized, but the type of argument it takes can. See https://ideone.com/KYQP2B

@k314159 I know, but the code in your link is exactly what OP didn't want. Quote: "my class cannot be parametrized to one type, and a single instance will serve different classes"

@Sweeper I know, I mentioned that at the end of my answer.

The following complete, executable example demonstrates that what you're trying to do is indeed possible. I've used List instead of Broker so that it doesn't require any external dependencies, but the concept is the same.
public class MyClass implements Function<Class<?>, List<?>> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass app = new MyClass();
        List<?> x = app.apply(AtomicInteger.class);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public List<?> apply(Class<?> aClass) {
        try {
            return List.of(aClass.getConstructor().newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

One thing to note is that the class is not generic, so you can't make x a List<AtomicInteger> (which it actually is at runtime) unless you cast it and suppress the warning. Therefore, you lose some type safety. I would recommend making the class generic to enable type safety, if that is possible. That means having to use multiple instances of the class, but that's not a problem as the instances are trivial.
